# Given a string, how to get every substring permutation where order DOESN'T matter

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

Let's say I was given a string "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" and I want 8 character long strings to be generated from it. However, I do not care about the order of each character when talking about each permutation. For example, this algorithm should give me

"bcdfghwx" instead of "cbdfghwx" and other variations in order. I need something to calculate every permutation ignoring order.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, but I can't think of a better way to explain it.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, I needed combinations. It has been a while since I have used either term, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: So which order-agnostic permutation do you want returned?

Comment: So, you want all subsets?... they are represented by numbers from 0 to 2**len(str)-1

Comment: Permutation is about ordering. The other two are combinations and variations. Do you want combinations? See http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/ats5/lcomb.htm

Comment: For longer strings, its almost impossible to enumerate all such permutations. The time complexity of the code is exponential. So, basically its futile to think over such a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, as mentioned in the comments, seems to just be the problem "get all subsets" or [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of a group of items, this can be done through basic recursion:

```java
static void print(int arr[],char values[]){
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if (arr[i]==1)
            System.out.print(values[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

static void powerSet(int arr[],char values[],int i,int j){
    // base case
    if(i>j){
        print(arr,values);
        return;
    }
    arr[i] = 1;
    // repeat with ith element included
    powerSet(arr,values,i+1,j);
    arr[i] = 0;
    // repeat with ith element excluded
    powerSet(arr,values,i+1,j);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] values = {'a','b','c'};
    // use, for example, int array to represent above list
    // i.e. {1,1,1} where '1' represents inclusion in your
    // set. So {1,1,0} would represent {a,b}.


    // initialize arr with 1s
    int[] arr = new int[values.length];
    Arrays.fill(arr, 1);

    powerSet(arr,values,0,values.length-1);

}
```

Output:

```
abc
ab
ac
a
bc
b
c
```

As you can see you'll get `(2^n)-1` combos since empty set is excluded.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to programming, so I didn't what the term was for this.